Calculating Stable Coins swap price from LP of a DEX
I'm a bit new to this and I am interested in how could I calculate the swap price with stable coins from the amount of tokens in LP? I've read the Token Swap Program and using the formula there looks to give right calculations for tokens except stable coins.
For example on Orca (SOL-USDC) market . How could I calculate the USDC/SOLANA price based on the tokens in that pool.
I am trying to find a way to calculate this from data I can get from the Solana RPC, rather than using third-party API's. Also interested in exactly how the price when executing a swap is calculated.

It might be worth looking at how the 3rd party APIs do the calculation if their code is open source, and then just copying that on your side
